# How do I change the color of the procedure separation line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I change the color of the procedure separation line in Visual Studio ?

You can see the separator in the attached screenshot.

[image]

I looked in the color options but I couldn't find the setting to change.

Answer (score 0):

In 2005, one moderator mentioned you can't
[You can't change the color of the line...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dfb96c1-4dbc-4f2b-aeba-163504a83c71/line-color-outlining?forum=vbide)

Possibly, I said possibly.. you can find it in this list depending on your version.
Mine in visual studio 2015 does not have it.
[image]

Else, if you can't find it on your studio, the answer is you can't change it.

In the link above Dylan mentioned this, it's worth a try.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions you suggested worked.